# can not search in sql using arabic language

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview, arabic

i have a problem with searching in sql and show data in gridview, i want to search using arabic language but no data show in gridview, although if i search using IDNo= int, it is working ok.

```css
zz = "SELECT Name, IDNo, birthplace, Nationality, Mobile, Occupation From PersonalData where Name Like  '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        Dim dataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(zz, myConnection)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("PersonalData")
        Dim dsview As New DataTable
        Dim bs As New BindingSource
        dataadapter.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Little Bobby tables alert!

Answer (score 3):

You should add `N` before the `Like` in (`N'%"...`)

```
"SELECT ...where Name Like  N'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

*Also - be aware of sql injection because it seems you're not doing it.*